What happens with a thread's arguments if thread creation fails?
Imagine I create a thread like this:
jthread thr( []( string &&str ) {}, move( str ) );

What happens if the thread creation fails ? Is the string guaranteed to keep its old contents ?

Just a thought from my side: I don't think this is thread-specific behaviour.

@EdisonvonMyosotis wishful thinking. "Undoing" anything is pretty difficult to do reliably; not doing it at all is preferred. There are STL functions that guarantee that something is not happening, but I don't think that's the case here...

Well, the standard is here: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf#subsubsection.32.4.3.1. There are no guarantees when decay-copy happens.

Function arguments are evaluated before the function itself executes. So by the time thread creation has succeeded or failed, the move out of the argument has already been completed. In quite a few typical implementations, that will destroy the string you pass (to prevent multiple deletion, it sets the string's pointer to data to a null pointer).

@JerryCoffin The problem is that evaluation of std::move(str) does nothing to str. str internal pointer is set to nullptr when the temporary is materialised somewhere within the call chain (I guess that's what decay-copy does) and it's entirely possible that an exception could be thrown before materialisation or after that.

If thread creation fails, either the OS or you app (99% the latter) has a serious stability issue.

@Yksisarvinen: In theory you sort of have a point. But for it to be a strong point, there would have to be something happening in the call chain that could/would actually throw an exception. Just for example, if another parameter were being passed by value, and it was something like a large vector that would require a memory allocation that could fail, then an exception would be a reasonable possibility. But in this case, we simply don't have much of anything that could throw such an exception.

In practice, the parameters of a std::thread call are stored in something like a std::tuple by-value.  This must be done in the context that creates the std::thread.  Then function object is invoked in a way similar to std::apply in the thread.
When the failure to create the actual threading primitives happens isn't going to be specified.  It could happen before the std::tuple used to marshal the arguments over to the new std::thread is created, or it could happen after.
Rough psuedo code for:
std::thread bob( func, arg1, arg2 );

is
std::thread ctor( F&& func, A1&&, arg1, A2&&, arg2 ) {
  // the data the thread needs to run:
  using package_t = std::tuple<std::decay_t<F>, std::decay_t<A1>, std::decay_t<A2>>;

  // bundle it up and put it on the heap:
  auto* ptmp = new package_t( std::forward<F>(func), std::forward<A1>(arg1), std::forward<A2>(arg2) );

  // use lower level primitives to interact with OS threading:
  m_pthread_handle = pthread_create(
    // Lower level function pointer:
    [](void* p){
      // unbundle the package of data and run the function on the arguments:
      auto* ptmp = static_cast<package*>(p);
      std::get<0>(*ptmp)( std::get<1>(std::move(*ptmp)), std::get<2>(std::move(*ptmp)) );
      // clean up
      delete ptmp;
    },
    ptmp
  );
}

with error checking/exception handling and lots of other detail skipped.
But, importantly, the fact that the bundle of parameters "ptmp" is created before we possibly have a failure in thread creation is not specified.

It's a note so it's not normative but it is backed up somewhere and this seems to indicate that copy has to happen before the thread starts, so it would seem like only an earlier exception in the initialization is the only way we could get an exception before the thread starts and the object is moved.

@NathanOliver Sure, but you can image creating a thread might be multiple step process in the originating thread.  And a failure could occur before we need to pass the tuple-thingy over to it.  This isn't the case if we are wrapping pthread or a similar API, so maybe never happens.

The answer is the same for both std::jthread and std::thread, so I'll answer this question for std::thread since that's the more common option.
std::thread has a two-step process when starting the thread.
As explained in [thread.thread.constr], the constructor performs:

invoke(auto(std::forward<F>(f)), auto(std::forward<Args>(args))...)


... where the values produced by auto are materialized in the constructing thread.
In other words, the current thread will copy or move all of the arguments into new objects.
Once the new thread has started, it will std::invoke the given function with those new objects.
Even if thread creation fails (std::system_error is thrown), your str will be moved from.
A way to circumvent unnecessary copies or moves is to pass std::ref(str) instead, so the constructing thread will only materialize a std::reference_wrapper.
Another common approach is to let the lambda handle everything:
std::jthread t( [&str] {
    std::string s = std::move(str);
    // ...
} );

However, both these solutions require you to keep str alive until the new thread has started; otherwise, you get undefined behavior.
This is typically fine when joining the thread on the constructing thread, but may not be fine if you .detach() and forget about t immediately.

Note: the corresponding wording for std::jthread is in [thread.jthread.cons].

I don't see anything saying that failure to create a thread cannot happen and throw already before the temporary objects are materialized. In fact, I would be more inclined to think that throwing during the "as-if" evaluation of the invoke expression wouldn't be complying as it would modify the semantics of that expression.

@user17732522 see https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.constr#6. The completion of the constructor synchronizes with the call to the given function (which happens on the new thread). In fall fairness, you're right that the implementation could "reserve" a new thread from the OS without putting any work on that, and this could already fail before the copies of the arguments. However, that would be a very outlandish implementation, and in practice, you bundle up the arguments into a tuple or something and then start a thread with a callback after.

So you're right in theory that it can happen before (in an awfully weird implementation). It also wouldn't be sane for thread creation failure to already happen on a separate thread, so it should not reasonably happen in the middle of copying the arguments. None of this is strictly forbidden though, based on the wording, as it's not said how the process of getting a thread from the OS works.

I don't think the synchronization requirement matters in the failure case because f isn't invoked at all in that case. Otherwise I agree with what your answers. However, the thread resources themselves are typically not the only ones that might not be available. The typical implementation needs to make a heap allocation and that can fail as well. In that case it will fail before the move-construction. The specification (which doesn't seem clear enough to me) should allow failure at both points.

@user17732522 the constructor has a Throws specification (https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.constr#8) and the way this is read that it cannot throw anything but this exception, so there isn't std::bad_alloc at least. Everything would be bundled up into that std::system_error presumably, even failure to heap-allocate. But yeah, you could in principle heap-allocate before doing anything with constructor arguments; you're not wrong there.

Yes, it's a problem with the specification: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#3475

The following code demonstrates how a thread-creation with parameter "undo" should look like:
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template<typename Fn, typename ... Args>
void xthread( Fn &&fn, Args &&... args )
{
    using thread_t = void *(*)( void * );
    using tupl_t = tuple<decay_t<Fn>, decay_t<Args> ...>;
    auto argsSeq = make_index_sequence<sizeof ...(Args)>();
    auto thr = []<size_t ... Indices>( index_sequence<Indices ...> ) -> thread_t
    {
        return []( void *param ) -> void *
            {
                unique_ptr<tupl_t> pTupl( (tupl_t *)param );
                get<0>( *pTupl )( get<Indices + 1>( *pTupl ) ... );
                return nullptr;
            };
    };
    auto fnObj = make_unique<tupl_t>( forward<Fn>( fn ), forward<Args>( args ) ... );
    if( pthread_t handle; !pthread_create( &handle, nullptr, thr( argsSeq ), fnObj.get() ) )
        fnObj.release(),
        pthread_join( handle, nullptr );
    else
    {
        auto back = []<typename Dst>( Dst &&dst, auto &&src )
        {
            if constexpr( is_rvalue_reference_v<Dst> && !is_const_v<Dst> )
                dst = move( src );
        };
        back( forward<Fn>( fn ), get<0>( *fnObj ) );
        [&]<size_t ... Indices>( index_sequence<Indices ...> )
        {
            (back( forward<Args>( args ), get<Indices + 1>( *fnObj.get() ) ), ...);
        }( argsSeq );
    }
}

int main()
{
    string str( "hello world" );
    xthread( []( string &str ) { cout << str << endl; }, move( str ) );
}

